# How do I append n zeroes to the end of each row of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2-dimensional numpy array and I want to extend each row by *n* zeroes.

Example of input array:

```
    array([[0 0 1]
           [1 1 1]
           [1 0 1]
           [0 1 1]])
```

Expected output for n = 1:

```
    array([[0 0 1 0]
           [1 1 1 0]
           [1 0 1 0]
           [0 1 1 0]])
```

How can this be done?

I have already tried adding a np.zeroes value to the array but that did not seem to work as intented.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: What is a term? Please share the expected output. Also don't name a list `list`, since it masks the builtin name. And that is a list not a numpy array

Comment: Changes made. It is actually a numpy array but I had to recreate it.

Comment: @VictorSim I see you've accepted my suggested edits re the phrasing of the question, but it would be worth also you editing the question to also mention anything you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the function [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) is for. Example:

```
>>> arr = np.random.rand(4, 3)
array([[0.49523083, 0.08740367, 0.81560756],
       [0.24770699, 0.49593462, 0.54695548],
       [0.69683291, 0.17064399, 0.94812849],
       [0.83924539, 0.38308905, 0.92745001]])
>>> np.pad(arr, ((0,0), (0,1)))
array([[0.49523083, 0.08740367, 0.81560756, 0.        ],
       [0.24770699, 0.49593462, 0.54695548, 0.        ],
       [0.69683291, 0.17064399, 0.94812849, 0.        ],
       [0.83924539, 0.38308905, 0.92745001, 0.        ]])
```

You could also wrap this into a function:

```
def append_zeros(arr, n): 
    return np.pad(arr, ((0,0), (0,n)))
```